# IOS bug constraints ViewDidAppear vs ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, break, viewdidappear

I work since 2 days on this problem without understanding the mindfuck behind it...
So to explain quickly, I create a view based on a Nib in an other storyboard like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TestNib", bundle: nil)
    testNib = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TestNib") as! TestNib
    testNib.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(testNib.view)
```

and I add some constraints manually with constraintsWithVisualFormat like this:

```
constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|-(10)-[conversationMenu(300)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
        metrics: nil, views: ["conversationMenu": testNib.view])
    let constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|[conversationMenu]|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
        metrics: nil, views: ["conversationMenu": testNib.view])

    self.view.addConstraints(constraint_V)
    self.view.addConstraints(constraint_H)
```

No problem, everything work super fine. (I also try with a view in the storyboard by the way).

The main problem is when I want to animate this view, the constraints into "testNib" (self.view.addSubview(testNib.view)) break. And this happened when I create the constraintsWithVisualFormat in the ViewDidAppear. In the ViewDidLoad everything work perfectly...

This are my instances' variables:

```
var testNib: TestNib!
var constraint_V: [NSLayoutConstraint]!
var completion = false
```

And this is my code to animate the constraints:

```
if completion == false {
        for constraint in constraint_V {
            if constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Top {
                constraint.constant = -200
            }
        }
    } else {
        for constraint in constraint_V {
            if constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Top {
                constraint.constant = 10
            }
        }
    }

    completion = !completion

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: {(value: Bool) in
    })
```

You will ask me, why if it work in the ViewDidLoad you simply do not use it?
It's because my main problem is when I "presentViewController" and dismiss it, constraints break again and the only way I found to reproduce this bug is to insert my initialization into the ViewDidAppear.

I have commit and push my code into a github if you want to test with me: https://github.com/Comanga/Bug-Constraints.

What you need to see is the green view that is not stuck anymore to the top constraint.

Oh you read this until this line? Thank you <3

iOS9 - SWIFT 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would help you

```
viewDidAppear is called finally after UIKit laid out sub views and displayed them.
```

So it is not working and you can think another way to re-layout your view controller after added/removed constraints.

try setNeedsUpdateConstraints or something